# How to Use hibernate Projections Without the Deprecated method Create Criteria. Is there any other ways use Projections without deprecated method

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, nhibernate-projections

Actually I have used Hibernate projections in the below code to sum multiple columns. I may send any number of column but the query will be generated according the number of column. *** The problem here is I have use an deprecated method *** I need the proper method to get the result.

```
public Object dynamicSum(String columns) {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(columns);
    JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("column");

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ItemListing.class);
    
    ProjectionList p1 = Projections.projectionList();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        p1.add(Projections.sum(array.getString(i)));
    }
    criteria.setProjection(p1);
    Object result = criteria.list();

    return result;
}
```

From the above code I Item Listing is my pojo class mapped with the DB table. the deprecated method is session is session.createCriteria. I have to use proper method to get result.
I am sharing my code image. In the Image I have underlined the deprecated method.

[image]